# removeClass & addClass jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild, removechild

I am relatively new to jquery and try to solve the following issue

I want to build a tree diagram, cf.

[image]

When an item in the first category is clicked, the second category (in div #category_2) pops-up. The same for the 3rd category. Every subsequent click on category 1 or 2 should remove the appended 2nd and 3rd item and append the chosen item from the 2nd and 3rd category.

Here is what I tried at the example of opening an item in category 3 (=subMenu2):

```js
function makeType(subMenu2, root) {
  if (typeof root === 'undefined') {
    root = $('#category_3');
  }

  var ul = $("<ul></ul>");

  if (root.children().length > 0) {
    root.removeClass(ul)
  }
 
  root.append(ul);

  for (var k = 0; k < subMenu2.length; k++) {
    var li = $("<li class='category-selection-list-item is-subleaf'></li>");
    ul.append(li);
    var a = $("<a href='#' data-param='" + array[array_i].subMenu[submenu_i].subMenu2[k].param + "'>" + array[array_i].subMenu[submenu_i].subMenu2[k].type + "</a>");
    li.append(a);
    console.log(k);
  }
}
```

Though the removeClass element stops adding further items, it does not delete previously added items. I tried to find a suitable answer in the forum, but this did not help. So, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is `ul` in `removeClass(ul)`?

Comment: also here what ul is used `.append(ul);` but it was declared your naming of var is confusing

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `root` instead of `$('#category_3')` in the `if()`?

Comment: The argument to `removeClass` should be a string. `ul` is a jQuery object, what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the previously added items, you need to empty `root`.

```
if (root.children().length > 0) {
    root.removeClass('ul');
    root.empty();
}
```

Comment: This is fairly simple an works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
addClass("className") 
removeClass("className")
```

if you want to hide some node, just use this:

```
 $("#someNode").hide()
```